# Was My Wordpress Site Hacked?

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu-18.04, html, css

I just checked my WordPress site ([Wherehouse MKE](http://WherehouseMKE.com)) and there is this bar that runs across the top of the page and when you click anywhere on the site it wants to open a spam page. Lucky the functionality of the site does not seem to be too compromised and this does not apply to the mobile version using chrome on an iPhone.

I am aware that many hacks can be different and it is very hard to find them and fix sites but I would appreciate pointers and helpful hints. The only reason I have not upload one of my total backups is because I am trying to fix this in a way that I don't loose orders and customer data off of the site.

Steps that I have taken to try to hunt down this hack are from this post [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/217266/my-wordpress-site-hacked-with-unwanted-popups). I have [wordfence](https://www.wordfence.com/) running a scan and I will report back if I find any script injections.

Comment: The answer to your headline question is almost certainly yes.

Comment: I see a "bar" across the top of the page with what looks like raw CSS in it. I do not see any links to spam sites. Except Instagram, I suppose... Maybe it's your own computer that's compromised?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I can assure you it's not. When you click anywhere on the site it should try to open a popup window.

Comment: I click anywhere on the site and nothing happens, unless it's on one of the Book Now links or Instagram photos.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Are you using chrome? Firefox does block them automatically. I have removed a few files and scripts so far.

Comment: Yes, I am using Firefox. In Chrome I do see the malicious link. I'm sure you're compromised now.

Comment: If you are truly running a business on such, then I suggest you use a hosted WordPress service (like WordPress.com) where they have security experts to really lock down the settings. There are tons of possibilities if you forget to patch the OS, web server, PHP runtime, WordPress, and the plugins you use, and you cannot compare your security experience with those who master the system.